# Suppose that $A = O \cap C$. Show that for any $a \in A$ there exists $U_a$ such that $U_a \cap A $ is closed in $U_a$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $A \subset X$ and suppose that $A = O \cap C$, where $O$ and $C$ are open and closed sets respectively. Show that for any $a \in A$ there exists $U_a$ such that $U_a \cap A $ is closed in $U_a$.

Attempt: Let $x \in A$, then $x \in O \cap C$. Now if $x \in O$, then since $O$ is open there exists open neighborhood $U_x \subset O$, but now $x \in U_x \cap C$ which is closed in $U_x$ by the subspace topology right?

Comment: You want $A \cap U_a$ closed in $U_a$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want $U_a$ to be an open set containing $a$.

You want $A \cap U_a$ closed in $U_a$ but you took intersection with $C$.

Just take $U_a=O$. Note that $A$ is closed on $O$.